# Application calls per minute from App dynamics

Tags: appdynamics

I was looking at a monitoring dashboard made out of app dynamics.

Here is the observation.
Application calls per minute from matrix browser at a given point of time.

```
    Observed 0
    Sum 4
    Count 288
```

What does this mean, how it’s getting calculated? Could any one please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

In the metric browser, you will find summarized metrics for a given time period. In the period you are looking at there are 0 calls, but int he graph there were 4 calls, and the total calls were 288. It's hard to tell what you are looking at, maybe attach a screenshot?